# How to search for a value in a multidimesional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to see if for example the value "2001" exists in the following multidimensional array for the [terms] key and if it does, I will do nothing.  If it doesn't exist, I need to add it into the array under [terms]:

```
Array
(
    [year] => Array
        (
            [singular] => Year
            [plural] => Years
            [filterable] => 1
            [use_on_listing] => 0
            [compare_value] => =
            [terms] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2014
                    [1] => 2013
                    [2] => 2012
                    [3] => 2010
                    [4] => 2009
                    [5] => 2015
                    [6] => 1997
                )

        )
 )
```

Can't seem to figure it out using array_search though.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: array_search only deals with single arrays. `array_search(2001, $arr['year']['terms'])` would work... it will not scan "down" into sub-arrays for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(! in_array ( $year , $my_array['year']['terms']) ) //do stuff
```

Where $my_array is whatever the array name is, and $year is whatever year you choose.

Comment: Looks like it's almost there, it does work, but also ouputs the following: Error: [8] Use of undefined constant year - assumed 'year'
Error: [8] Use of undefined constant terms - assumed 'terms'

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the quotes. The edited version should have single quotes around each.

Comment: Hah I was about to try that and yeah that got rid of the error.  Looks good to go now.  Thanks again!